getting pid of the background job using "$!"
I've a written a shell script to launch multiple background jobs and store the process id's of them in an array using $!. In the end I print all the process id's by iterating through the array. I want to know is the shell script written has a bug? And, the reason I feel there is a bug in my shell script is because $! might return the process id of another process if in case there are multiple processes being created in my PC.
#!/bin/bash

ps -a & pids+=($!) #Does $! return process id of command ps -a for sure
ls -la & pids+=($!) #Does $! return process id of command ls -la for sure
echo ${pids[0]}
echo ${pids[1]}


It's unclear what your question is. Why would $! return the pid of another process? It contains the PID of the job "most recently placed into the background" (by the shell), so any processes created outside of the shell are irrelevant.

I thought $! holds pid of newly created process(system wide)

No, it doesn't, it's local to your shell script (and applies only to backgrounded processes).

Is this a shell (tag) or Bash question?

$! "expands to the process ID of the most recently executed background (asynchronous) command" (source: bash manual)
The variable is local to the current shell instance, so anything that happens outside of the current shell script/session is not relevant.
If you place two processes in the background:
ps -a &
ls -la &

Then $! will contain the PID of the last backgrounded process (in this case, ls -la).
